# How to do android beta testing

Tags: android, testing, google-play

I am new to android developing. I have just finished building my first app, which I want to publish in the play store. But, before that I want to test it using the android's open beta testing service. I read android's developer material, also went through some of the questions already asked here. But, I didn't get info what I am looking for.

Please help me with the following..

1. To beta test, should I upload the APK in the debug version or the release  version?
2. If it is a release version, how can I generate a signed APK?

Answer (score 0):

You need a release version to post it in Google Play.

The steps are listed in the following link:
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Upload your apk to Google Play and you will have options to distribute it in open beta mode.

Comment: Thank you. Should I give only the google emails of the testers in the google play??